# Replace Hashtag-separated values with Comma-separated values using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, str-replace

Trying to turn..

```
#one #two #three
```

into

```
one, two, three
```

Almost got it working but it misses the first one..

Code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to replace " #" with ", " in the paragraph below:</p>

<p id="demo">#one #two #three</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
  var res = str.replace(/ #/g, ", ");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GALOV6REXR1C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a callback where the function can be used to distinguish the replace value

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Click the button to replace " #" with ", " in the paragraph below:</p>

  <p id="demo">#one #two #three</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
      var res = str.replace(/^#|( #)/g, (_, m1) => m1 ? ", " : '');
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd `.match` substrings that have a `#` right before them, and then `.join` by commas:

```js
const str = '#one #two #three';
const arr = str.match(/(?<=#)\S+/g);
const output = arr.join(', ');
console.log(output);
```

Without lookbehind, if the hashtags are separated by spaces, split by spaces, `.map` to remove the first hash character from each, then join:

```js
const str = '#one #two #three';
const output = str
  .split(' ')
  .map(hashtag => hashtag.slice(1))
  .join(', ');
console.log(output);
```